# Using PHP to echo a HTML table

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a user attendance script with PHP, I basically want the structure that looks like the below:

Or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSsKg/)

```
<form action='this_page.php' method='post'>
<table>
    <th>Member</th>
    <th>Day One</th>
    <th>Day Two</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Memeber One</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Member Two</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I've got this working dynamically without any database interactions and the day numbers are working correctly with the below code:

```
<?php 
$startDate = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('2013-09-31');
$days = array();

for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {
       echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>";array_push($days,$c); }
 ?>
```

From this I expanded to introduce database interactions as I want to show the users that are in my database.

The below function shows what I have so far but I've run into a problem

**1. The dynamic function which shows me the dates are not appearing on the same line as the other table headers e.g. the dates are above the table header firstname.**

**How can I fix this? I haven't worked too much with tables so am not sure what I've done work. Any ideas?**

```
public function viewall() {
            $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users");
    $sth->execute();


    /* Fetch all of the values of the first column */
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $table = "<form action='' method='post'>
            <table>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>";
                $startDate = new DateTime();
                $endDate = new DateTime('2013-09-31');
                $days = array();

                for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {
                       echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>";array_push($days,$c); }

            foreach($result as $row) {
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
           $lastname = $row['lastname'];
           $table .= "<tr>
                <td>$firstname</td>
                <td>$lastname</td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='$firstname' value='Y' /></td>
            </tr>
            </table></form>";
            echo $table;
        }

}
```

Comment: Between `<table>` and `<th>` there is a `<tr>` missing, as later a `</tr>`.

Comment: @Joop this doesn't change it at all, i've tried this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table>
<th>Member</th>
<th>Day One</th>
<th>Day Two</th>
```

needs to become

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Member</th>
    <th>Day One</th>
    <th>Day Two</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work either, this is how I have tried this: `<tr><th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th>";for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th></tr>";array_push($days,$c); }` didn't even change it slightly

Comment: not to worry adam you are correct, it the way I've formatted my code I've removed the `<tr>` to a separate echo and this has worked! +1 and will accept the answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

The dates you `echo` immediately; you should concat them too to `table`.

Answer (score 0):

You echo your datetime  before you echo your table

Try to change this code :

```
echo "<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>";array_push($days,$c);
```

into this  :

```
$table.="<th>".$c->format('d')."</th>";array_push($days,$c);
```